# How to enqueue stylesheet after rtl.css?

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style

When you use rtl language by default wordpress enqueue rtl.css file at the end of all stylesheets. what I need is how to enqueue a stylesheet after rtl.css stylesheet so the result should be like the following?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/rtl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/responsive-rtl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Thanks

Comment: When you use rtl language by default wordpress enqueue rtl.css file at the end of all stylesheets What I need is to enqueue a file after rtl.css? is_rtl() just check if the current language is rtl or not but I can't enqueue a file after rtl.css

Comment: Please ensure that WordPress core, and not your *theme*, is responsible for enqueueing the RTL stylesheet. Does the RTL stylesheet get enqueued if the site is using a core-bundled Theme (such as Twenty Twelve)?